# How to exit a cmd shell after running batch file?

Tags: vb.net, shell, batch-file, console, hide

I have this piece of VB.Net code:

```
Private Sub
    Android50LPreviewToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Android50LPreviewToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Shell("cmd /K c:\Zeustools\frameworks\apktool if framework-res_apiL.apk ", vbHide)
End Sub
```

How do exit/kill the cmd console after the above operation is finished?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using cmd /c instead of cmd /k?

/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates 
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains

```
D:\>cmd /?
Starts a new instance of the Windows XP command interpreter

CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]
    [[/S] [/C | /K] string]

/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
/S      Modifies the treatment of string after /C or /K (see below)
/Q      Turns echo off
/D      Disable execution of AutoRun commands from registry (see below)
/A      Causes the output of internal commands to a pipe or file to be ANSI
/U      Causes the output of internal commands to a pipe or file to be
        Unicode
/T:fg   Sets the foreground/background colors (see COLOR /? for more info)
/E:ON   Enable command extensions (see below)
/E:OFF  Disable command extensions (see below)
/F:ON   Enable file and directory name completion characters (see below)
/F:OFF  Disable file and directory name completion characters (see below)
/V:ON   Enable delayed environment variable expansion using ! as the
        delimiter. For example, /V:ON would allow !var! to expand the
        variable var at execution time.  The var syntax expands variables
        at input time, which is quite a different thing when inside of a FOR
        loop.
/V:OFF  Disable delayed environment expansion.
```